# Help give an example that $x^Ty \le 0$ but $x^TV^TVy >0$ where $V$ is full rank

Tags: linear-algebra

$x,y\in \Bbb R^n,V\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$. Help give an example that $x^Ty \le 0$ but $x^TV^TVy >0$ where $V$ is some full rank matrix. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x=(-1,-1)$, $y=(1,0)$,
$$V = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\&-1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}.$$

Then $Vx=-x = (1,1)$ and $Vy=y=(1,0)$.

---

Geometrically, the idea is the following. You want $x$ and $y$ to have an obtuse angle, but you want $Vx$ and $Vy$ to have an acute angle. In the above example, I have chosen $V$ to keep $y$ fixed while moving $x$ to produce the desired inequalities.